# OpenCV stream video from Netcat

Tags: c++, opencv, netcat

I am using **Netcat** and **Mplayer** to stream video from one device to another like this:

```
cat [video file] | nc [client ip address] [port] (server)

nc -L -p [port] | mplayer [options]              (client)
```

I would like to ask if there is a way to pick up the stream with **OpenCV** to perform some image processing.

I have tried something like

```
VideoCapture stream("udp://@<ip>:<port>/");
```

but the process gets stuck at this point.

Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 1):

I'm doing a similar thing myself, was able to get it working by simply piping through stdin:

`nc -L -p [port] | ./opencvprogram`

and then in the opencv program:

`VideoCapture stream("/dev/stdin");`

Comment: I got error when opening device.`isOpened()` return false. what's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try

```
VideoCapture stream("udp://@:6000"); //6000 is just an example
```

?

Are you sure that your video is streaming as UDP?

You can check this [code](http://answers.opencv.org/question/133/how-do-i-access-an-ip-camera/) too.